# PHP Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's my current code:

```
<?php 
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];

include_once '../../dbconnect.php';

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE apikey='$key' && status='Active'");
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$conn->close();

/// Verify the URL starts with http:// or https://
if (0 === strpos($url, 'http://') || 0 === strpos($url, 'https://')) {
$url = $url;
} else {
$url = "http://$url";
}

/// Verify the key is 32 characters
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $key) && (strlen($key) == 32)) {

/// Verify the URL isn't malicious
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    die('Error:  Invalid URL');
} else {

if ($userRow['status'] === 'Active') {

function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$redirect = generateRandomString();

$addshort = $conn->query("INSERT INTO short_".$redirect[0]." (redirect, apikey, url) VALUES ('".$redirect."','".$key."','".$url."')");

if ($conn->query($addshort) === TRUE) {
echo "added correctly";
} else {
echo "there was an error";
}

$conn->close();

} else {
echo "Error:  Account Not Active";
}

}

} else {
die('Error:  Invalid API Key');
}
?>
```

Here's the error_log:

```
[18-Oct-2016 12:21:31 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/username/public_html/subdomains/url/index.php on line 40
[18-Oct-2016 12:21:31 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Empty query in /home/username/public_html/subdomains/url/index.php on line 42
[18-Oct-2016 12:21:31 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/username/public_html/subdomains/url/index.php on line 48
```

You can see on the 7th line where I connect to the database for the first time:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE apikey='$key' && status='Active'");
```

And that line is working.  However, the second time I'm connecting to do an `INSERT`, I'm getting the above errors:

```
$addshort = $conn->query("INSERT INTO short_".$redirect[0]." (redirect, apikey, url) VALUES ('".$redirect."','".$key."','".$url."')");
```

Is there something I'm missing from just staring at this code for too long?

Comment: chk your connection first

Comment: Connection shouldn't be an issue, otherwise the first query should fail.

Comment: u have already closed your connection after selection `$conn->close();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your connection has been closed, after execution of first SELECT Statement, it means connection closed to early:

```
$conn->close();
```

You need to use `close()` after your all queries or re build connection. ist one is the better option.

*You are getting user input `$_REQUEST['key']`, it means your query is open for SQL injection, this will help you to understand how can you prevent your code with SQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

Comment: That fixed it perfectly! I'll accept in 4 minutes, once SO lets me.  Any idea why `echo "there was an error";` is running instead of `echo "added correctly";`?  The rows are being added to the database correctly, so I'm not sure why the error is occurring...

Comment: @JamesSandzalone:this is very interesting, for this error you need to check MArkB answer.. :)

Comment: James, @marc-b already mentioned, about this problem, :)

Comment: @JamesSandzalone: dont fogot SQL injection veryi very important...

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
$addshort = $conn->query("INSERT ...')");
^^^^^^^
if ($conn->query($addshort) === TRUE) {
                   ^^^^^
```

`$addshort` is your query result/handle/object, which you then try to EXECUTE **AGAIN**, which doesn't work. `query()` expects an SQL string, and you're passing in an object.

And on top of that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).